# What's the appropriate sentence using "close", meaning "out of business"?

Tags: meaning

Yesterday I went to the drugstore where I haven't been for a long time, but it was closed, I mean, it was out of business.  In this case, which sentence should I use?  I'm saying to someone at that moment, 1) It's closed. 2) It's been closed. 3)It closed. 4)It closed down.  I'd like to put the meaning that this is permanent.

Comment: I'd vote for 4) closed down - that way there's no doubt remaining.

Comment: The best way (IMO) is to forego "closed" in favor of "out of business": _They went out of business_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's closed.

The shop is not currently open for business

> It's been closed.

At some point in the past, the shop wasn't open for business (sounds awkward, you would say "it was closed" instead). Or: Someone has closed the shop for the day (still sounds awkward, you would say "it's closed")

> It closed

The shop has closed down forever

> It closed down

Same as above, the shop has closed down forever

Comment: "It closed" on its own does _suggest_ a permanent closure, but it is a weak suggestion, easily broken by additional timeline information.  "I tried to get bread from the store, but it closed before I got there."

Comment: Everything is very clear now.  Thak you.